# Boost: unrecognised option for positional argument

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

I'm trying to parse command line with boost 1.58.0. My code is quite simple and copy\pasted from the tutorials. It looks like that:

```
 try {
        po::options_description desc;
        desc.add_options()
                ("version,v", "Display version of application.");

        po::positional_options_description p;
        p.add("input-file", -1);

        try
        {
            po::store(po::command_line_parser(argc, argv).
                      options(desc).positional(p).run(), vm);

            if ( vm.count("version")  )
            {
                std::cout << "Program version: " << SHUF_T_VERSION << std::endl << "Boost library version: " << BOOST_LIB_VERSION << std::endl;
                return false;
            }

            po::notify(vm); // throws on error, so do after help in case
            // there are any problems
        }
        catch(po::error& e)
        {
            std::cerr << "ERROR: " << e.what() << std::endl << std::endl;
            std::cerr << desc << std::endl;
            return false;
        }

    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Unhandled Exception: "
                  << e.what() << ", application will now exit" << std::endl;
        return false;

    }

  return true;
```

The whole code is [here](http://pastebin.com/Ap2YZXLm).
The code seems to be correct. The `app -v` is processed correctly. But if I include any positional arguement, like `app myfile` the `po::store()` throws `unrecognised option 'myfile'`. Any ideas on why this is hapening?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to add "input-file" as an option:

```
po::options_description desc;
desc.add_options()
        ("version,v", "Display version of application.")
        ("input-file", po::value<std::vector<std::string> >(), "input file");
```

From [the tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/program_options/tutorial.html#idp343103984):

> The "input-file" option specifies the list of files to process. That's okay for a start, but, of course, writing something like:
>
> ```
> compiler --input-file=a.cpp
> ```
>
> is a little non-standard, compared with
>
> ```
> compiler a.cpp
> ```
>
> We'll address this in a moment.
>
> The command line tokens which have no option name, as above, are called "positional options" by this library. They can be handled too. With a little help from the user, the library can decide that "a.cpp" really means the same as "--input-file=a.cpp". Here's the additional code we need:
>
> ```
> po::positional_options_description p;
> p.add("input-file", -1);
>
> po::variables_map vm;
> po::store(po::command_line_parser(ac, av).
>           options(desc).positional(p).run(), vm);
> po::notify(vm);
> ```

Comment: And what if you don't want to add an long/short option for positional arguments?